# Part of rear brakes for 2000 Tracker

Tags: brakes, part-identification

My 2000 Tracker's rear brake cylinder blew.  The mechanic said that among the parts needed was something I can't remember the name of.  It was bent and therefore comprimised.  He said it is not easy to locate in the parts stores.  It looks almost like a wrench but is not the spacer.

Can anyone tell me what the name of it is?

Comment: Does this vehicle have disc or drum brakes?

Answer (score 1):

From your description the part you need is the rear shoe spreader. It is a flat piece of metal that is part of the mechanism that actuates your parking brake. It can be difficult to locate because it has no moving parts and lasts forever unless the rear shoes wear so much that the wheel cylinders over extend and fail. The shoes moved so far out that the spreader fell out of position and most likely wedged between the shoes and the drums.